# Rebuild url_title fields?

Tags: entries, url-title

I have a site with 1000's of products that were originally entered incorrectly. The titles have been updated, but the URL title's still have the old data. Is it possible to bulk update these entries to with either a sql query or script?

Answer (score 6):

You can do a bulk update of URL Titles with SQL like:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_titles SET url_title=REPLACE( LOWER(title) , ' ', '-') WHERE channel_id=1
```

You can see URL Title is being derived from Title replacing space with dash and changing in lower case. You can have channel_id and any other condition in WHERE according to your preference.

You can have second approach by writing script using Channel Entry API like:

```
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
        $this->EE->load->library('api');
        $this->EE->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
        $this->EE->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

    $channel_id = 'Channel id number here';

        $entries = $this->EE->db->select('entry_id, title')->where('channel_id', $channel_id)->get('channel_titles')->result_array();
        foreach($entries as $entry)
        {
            $data = array(
                    'title' => $entry['title'],
'channel_id' => 'channel id number'
                );
            $this->EE->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings($channel_id, $data);
            $this->EE->api_channel_entries->update_entry($entry['entry_id'], $data);
        }
```

Comment: What about replacing special characters and duplicate title's to increment correctly?

Comment: yes, this was also in my mind and my second way was to write  script using Channel Entry API. It would help you. See my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, how would I initiate this script?

Comment: You can EITHER develop a small plugin and put plugin tag within a template OR just put the code within a PHP enabled template and run the template URL in browser. An extensive way would be to develop a module having action so that you can have URL like http://www.yoursite.com/?ACT=[ACTION ID]

Comment: Getting a parse error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code on line 13`

Comment: updated... last line of code was  missing semi colon....

Comment: New error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code on line 15`

Comment: Sorry Siebird! There doesn't seem any parse error in the code example of my answer and I don't know how are you putting the Channel Entry API.

Comment: Just enabled PHP in the template and hitting that URL. Should I set it to input or output?

Comment: no matter for input or output as you have only PHP code within template. right?

Comment: Hmmm, getting a different error now: `Undefined variable: channel_id`. Template code: http://d.pr/n/nBVz

Comment: hmmmm .... this approach should be fairly easy. either you should define $channel_id variable first or give the channel id number within the function. I edited my answer again.

Comment: Hmmmm...now: `Could not create/update entry. Missing api parameter.`

Comment: ahhhh .... i 'm sorry for your inconvenience. I thought with my pointer, you can move further easily. The $data array also need to pass channel_id. Please see the updated answer for it. Could you please let me know how you are running channel API as i am afraid if you face authorization issue as you need to logged in with authorized member or login manually like (http://www.sidd3.com/manually-login-a-member-in-expressionengine/). I hope, now you would face any issue. Please share if any further issue.

Comment: Script ran without errors finally :), but unfortunately the URL Title fields didn't update

Answer (score 1):

[Bhashkar's answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/10276/55) is great - though a quicker solution might be to install [Title Master](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-master). It has an option to update the URL title for all entries in a particular channel at once - and it's also an incredibly useful add-on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URL title to follow the same format as in the CP when creating an entry. Eg My Title is my-title then a simple PHP script could batch change these as both fields are in the same table.